# Registry key for sql server 2008 r2

Tags: c#

I am trying to set a condition for installing sql sever 2008 r2 on Advanced Installer.There is version for checking sql server 2012 r. Does anyone know the key for checking for sql server 2008 r2

SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Microsoft SQL Server\110\Tools\ClientSetup\CurrentVersion

Comment: SQL Server 2008 R2 is no longer supported. Any installations would require downgrading from a 2012+ license

Comment: Ok I have an application which uses sql server 2008 r express

Comment: Use a newer version then. 2016 SP1 adds compression, partitioning, columnstore, in-memory table support even in Express and LocalDB versions. Using these features would give a boost to your application without requiring a lot of effort

Comment: The only limitation is the target OS - 2016 installs only on supported Windows versions, ie Windows 7+, Server 2012+. 2014 installs on older OSs too